# XSD to validate element containing sequence and attributes

Tags: xml, xsd

Why my XSD is not working for following XML structure?
It says 'Invalid content was found starting with element 'Rights'. No child element is expected at this point.'

XML:

```
<Root>...
   <Rights Status="xxx" Date="2009-02-03T00:00:00">
      <Right>
         <Amount>9999</Amount>
         <AmountCovered>888</AmountCovered>
      </Right>
      <Right>
         <Amount>8888</Amount>
         <AmountCovered>777</AmountCovered>
      </Right>
      ...
   </Rights>
   ...
```

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="Rights" minOccurs="0">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Right" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:all>
                  <xs:element name="Amount" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                  <xs:element name="AmountCovered" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
               </xs:all>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="Status" use="optional" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="Date" use="optional" type="xs:dateTime" />
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the root element `<Rights>` cannot be specified with minOccurs="0"
remove the minOccurs in `<xs:element name="Rights">` or wrap another root element outside the `<Rights>`

XSD:

      `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="root">
      <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="Rights" minOccurs="0">
         ...
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>`

Comment: Hi I just edited my code, <Rights> is not root element, so the issue must be somwhere else